# Extracting the last component (basename) of a filesystem path

Tags: strings, memory-management, url, rust

```
fn basename<'a>(path: &'a str, sep: char) -> Cow<'a, str> {
    let pieces = path.split(sep);
    match pieces.last() {
        Some(p) => p.into(),
        None => path.into(),
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
println!("'{}'", basename("foo", '/'));    // outputs 'foo'
println!("'{}'", basename("bob/", '/'));   // outputs ''
println!("'{}'", basename("/usr/local/bin/rustc", '/')); // outputs 'rustc'
```

I think the `split()` into a `match` on `last()` is kind of elegant.
I know there is some work needed to handle both `str` and `String`, I am not sold on the use of `Cow` and needing to define a lifetime for the string.

I am not sold on `Cow` because later on I need to extract from it.

```
let prog = basename(&args[0], '/').into_owned();
```

It feels like I am working too hard.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Rust, but in other languages I would use `lastIndexOf` to find the last occurrence of a substring within a string.

Comment: Yup, that is what `last()` is doing @SimonAndréForsberg. In Rust the `split()` makes an iterator. Converting it to an array or the like would be a bit of overkill.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you should use `rsplit` and `next` rather than `split` and `last`, as it starts at the more appropriate end:

```
fn basename<'a>(path: &'a str, sep: char) -> Cow<'a, str> {
    let pieces = path.rsplit(sep);
    match pieces.next() {
        Some(p) => p.into(),
        None => path.into(),
    }
}
```

Secondly, you shouldn’t be using strings for this; you should be using [paths](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/index.html), because that’s semantically what you’re dealing with.

The easiest way to get a path tends to be to take a `&Path` or a generic parameter implementing `AsRef<Path>` and calling `.as_ref()` on it; `str`, `String`, `Path`, `PathBuf` and more implement it.

You can get the base name from a `&Path` with [`file_name`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.file_name); this admittedly produces a `Option<&OsStr>`, so if you want to *display* the path you’d need to convert it back towards a string with e.g. `.and_then(|s| s.to_str())`.

Anyway, the point of this latter part is just that for something that is semantically a path, you should be handling it specially, as a rule; a path need not be Unicode. Think on it more.

Comment: A few problems with this answer.  I'm new to Rust, and one of the 1st tasks is processing command line args, which includes the program path in args[0].  First, it was unclear from code example above what "use" dependencies there are (`use std::borrow::Cow;`).  Why even depend on Cow, and what is it?  2nd, the syntax seems peculiar, and the `'a` throws off syntax highlighting, further making it needlessly confusing.  Third, it requires a path separator.  I'm on windows, and depending if I call from a command prompt or MSYS2, the separator can be `/` or `\ `. How to determine that dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

```
pub fn basename<'a>(path: &'a str) -> Cow<'a, str> {
    let mut pieces = path.rsplitn(2, |c| c == '/' || c == '\\');
    match pieces.next() {
        Some(p) => p.into(),
        None => path.into(),
    }
}
```

This works for Unix or Windows path separators and does the least amount of work since it breaks the string into two pieces, the basename and the rest.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].